# Scalable airflow alternative

Tags: operations-orchestration, apache-airflow

I have a compute intensive DAG with dozens of tasks. each task is running a kubernetes pod using the airflow kubernetes operator.  I currently use Apache Airflow to orchestrate these tasks.
when i run my DAG many times concurrently the airflow server doesn't handle the load and starts returning errors. ( I am using a managed airflow -> gcp composer)
I enjoy the simplicity and flexibility of airflow but it just doesn't handle the scale that i require
I am looking for an alternative solution that will be able to scale

can anyone recommend on something?

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. There is [softwarerecs.se] for that.